# Criptografar string com base em uma palavra chave em php

Tags: php, criptografia

Eu gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de criptografar um string de forma reversível com base em uma senha. Para poder descriptografar é preciso saber a senha.
Assim como `base64_encode()` e `base64_decode()` porem que use uma palavra chave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, procure pelas funções [openssl_encrypt](https://secure.php.net/openssl_encrypt) e [openssl_decrypt](https://secure.php.net/openssl_decrypt).

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/56571)

Comment: Embora você tenha razão aí é interessante ver como essa é exatamente a mesma resposta que a aceita no SO en http://stackoverflow.com/a/9262137/3331294. Alterei a resposta para "procure por" assim os links são apenas referência agora, quando tiver tempo dou uma delineada no uso.

Answer (score 1):

Se tu quiser algo do tipo um sistema mensagem em que somente o usuário e aquele com quem le conversa pode ler a mensagem, tipo eles ter um código secreto entre eles ficaria assim:

```
function encrypt($mensagem, $a_chave_do_usuario){
$salt = SALT;
$key = substr(hash('sha256', $salt.$key.$salt), 0, 32);
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
$encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
return $encrypted;
}

function decrypt($mensagem, $a_chave_do_usuario){
$salt = SALT;
$key = substr(hash('sha256', $salt.$key.$salt), 0, 32);
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
$decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, base64_decode($data), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
return $decrypted;
}
```

O SALT seria uma constante do sistema tipo: 'A3jdh$4D8gkb#2T7&sM40bn4A7fvv35cf=b48On=84c!623Vvf6vi37vb34@3kf%'
Já a chave do usuário seria quaquer coisa que ele queira ao mandar uma mensagem, por exemplo se ele combinasse com alguém uma palavra chave entre os dois só eles dois poderiam decodificar a mensagem.

Para que tu possas ter uma ideia,

Se o usuário digitar 'eu' e colocar como frase secreta 'é sigiloso' o resultado esse SALT ai é exatamente:

yKwhaIqvlh2cLgLe4TXXC1No5W8gVpUj6rRpNG6/EME=

Dificilmente alguém saberia que isso ai em cima é a palavra 'eu'. Só o fulano A e o fulano B poderiam ler isso, nem o administrador do sistema saberia o que eles estão falando entre si, pois pois os dois combinaram que usariam a palavra chave 'é sigiloso' entre eles. A não ser que o desenvolvedor guarde a palavra chave de cada mensagem em algum lugar, só para xeretar as conversas alheias kkkk.

Espero que ajude, as possibilidades são infinitas.
Minha sessão usa algo parecido um pouco mais complicado, pois usa 2 chaves. Uma do sistema com bastante caracteres alfanuméricos e especiais de 64 dígitos e uma dinâmica com 128 caracteres gerada com sha512.

Comment: O `mcrypt_encrypt` já está obsoleto seu uso deve ser evitado, assim como o `mcrypt_create_iv` está obsoleto. Além disso, acredito que se o intuito for trafegar mensagem acho que o melhor seria utilizar o `gnupg` para isso e armazenar a chave privada do usuário localmente, isso é o dispositivo do usuário é quem tem a chave, dessa forma o "administrador do sistema" não teria acesso a chave. A chave é muito mais forte do que a senha, inclusive a chave do PGP pode ter senha. O `salt` nunca deve ser uma constante.

Comment: A ideia está correta, mas como o ```mcrypt_encrypt``` está depreciado, uma opção seria utilizar o ```openssl_encrypt```

Answer (score 0):

Bom-dia, ainda estou aprendendo e gostaria de entender o significado da palavra *"PALAVRA_CHAVE"* está ali, seria no caso a palavra para codificar e decodificar a string ?

Obrigado desde já!

```
public static final String CHAVE = "PALAVRA_CHAVE";

public static String criptografia(String senha) {
    String aux = "";
    int tamanhoString = senha.length();
    int tamanhoChave = CHAVE.length();

    if (tamanhoString > tamanhoChave) {
        senha = senha.substring(0, CHAVE.length());
    }
    senha = Funcoes.rTrim(senha);

    for (int i = 0; i < senha.length(); i++) {
        int pos = i / tamanhoChave;
        if (pos == 0) {
            pos = tamanhoChave;
        }
        int posLetra = senha.charAt(i) ^ CHAVE.charAt(i);
        if (posLetra == 0) {
            posLetra = senha.charAt(i);
        }
        aux += (char) posLetra;
    }
    return aux;
}

public static String rTrim(String s) {
    int i = s.length() - 1;
    while (i > 0 && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
        i--;
    }
    return s.substring(0, i + 1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Tem sim, eu tenho algumas criptografias feito em java/delphi/android um exemplo simples que posso te passar é esse:

```
public static final String CHAVE = "PALAVRA_CHAVE";

public static String criptografia(String senha) {
    String aux = "";
    int tamanhoString = senha.length();
    int tamanhoChave = CHAVE.length();

    if (tamanhoString > tamanhoChave) {
        senha = senha.substring(0, CHAVE.length());
    }
    senha = Funcoes.rTrim(senha);

    for (int i = 0; i < senha.length(); i++) {
        int pos = i / tamanhoChave;
        if (pos == 0) {
            pos = tamanhoChave;
        }
        int posLetra = senha.charAt(i) ^ CHAVE.charAt(i);
        if (posLetra == 0) {
            posLetra = senha.charAt(i);
        }
        aux += (char) posLetra;
    }
    return aux;
}

public static String rTrim(String s) {
    int i = s.length() - 1;
    while (i > 0 && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
        i--;
    }
    return s.substring(0, i + 1);
}
```

Se você passar um senha 1234 pra função, ela vai te retornar #$%$ por exemplo, e se você passar a criptografia, a função te devolve a senha original, aí é questão de você adaptar a sua lógica e fazer em php.

Comment: Isso é uma [Cifra de Vigenère](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifra_de_Vigen%C3%A8re)! Interessante, e historicamente relevante, mas totalmente insegura desde antes mesmo de inventarem os computadores rsrs.

Answer (score -3):

Como gerar uma chave para discriptografa 
Um email [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você poderia melhorar o enunciado da sua dúvida